# Rigorously showing that steady state will be reached in simple DC circuits

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, steady-state

Consider a simple DC circuit in which we have a source of emf connected to some resistance $R$.
Now all the books I have consulted give me heuristic arguments as to why a steady state will soon be reached and the current will be uniform everywhere.They go like, in the transient stage accumulation of charges does happen and these charges make sure that no further accumulation happens and also redirect the current along the loop.Can we show this mathematically that a steady state will soon be reached in the above mentioned circuit?
Also is there a way to analyze the transient stage of the circuit?

Answer (score 1):

Not all circuits will reach steady state given a constant source of energy (such as the voltage source in your example).  In fact, we often intentionally construct circuits which do not reach a steady state.  The clock driving the CPU in your computer, for instance, is designed to begin oscillating reliably given a constant input.

You mention "simple DC circuits."  A common interpretation of "simple" here is a circuit made of passive components: resistors, inductors, and capacitors.  In this case, we can prove that any such circuit must reach a steady state by exploring the frequency response of the circuit.  Doing so gets into AC analysis, but that's probably okay.  One of the things you can prove is that these passive components are *linear* in the frequency domain and a consequence of that is that they can only produce a steady state output at the same frequency as their input.  If the input to a linear circuit is at 100Hz, it must eventually reach an output that's at 100Hz and only 100Hz.  Since the circuit is being fed with a DC input (frequency = 0), its steady state<sup>1</sup> output must also be DC.  (the above example of a clock is a decidedly non-linear circuit, so it is not bound by this rule).

The transient region can be explored.  The most common approach to this is to do the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) which converts the differential equations governing how the circuit behaves into easy to work with algebraic ones.  The shape of those algebraic expressions can be used to determine the transient response to any particular input.

For more complicated circuits, especially those with non-linear elements like transistors in them, the analysis can be more complicated.

<sup>1</sup> I call this "steady state" to match the question about DC systems.  Arguably it isn't a steady state in the general sense, but a limit.  More pedantically, the state of the circuit must converge onto something which oscillates at the same frequency as the input.  For DC, these concepts are one and the same.

Comment: "One of the things you can prove is that these passive components are linear in the frequency domain and a consequence of that is that they can only produce a steady state output at the same frequency as their input" can you give me the proof of the above thing or atleast cite a source ,please!?

Comment: @Arjun Wikipedia's [Linear Time Invariant System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_time-invariant_system) page's Overview section contains: "Since sinusoids are a sum of complex exponentials with complex-conjugate frequencies, if the input to the system is a sinusoid, then the output of the system will also be a sinusoid, perhaps with a different amplitude and a different phase, but always with the same frequency upon reaching steady-state. LTI systems cannot produce frequency components that are not in the input. "  The math behind the proof is typically done in the Laplace domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can, in the context of a model, show mathematically that the circuit reaches a steady state. But that's mere mathematics. All such models are simplified abstractions. No mathematics is ever rigorous physics.

If a linear model suffices, the usual way we tackle these problems is by inspecting the roots of the denominator of the Laplace transform of the system response. If all of the roots have negative real parts, the system is damped and will reach a stable steady state. The inverse Laplace transform gives you the transient response.

But sometimes reality surprises us. No circuit is perfectly linear, and it's impossible to account for every little bit of charge accumulation and induction. Sometimes, a circuit you expected to be stable will turn out not to be. Mathematics can only take you so far: reality has the last word.

If you really want a balanced understanding of this subject, you must spend a substantial amount of time building and testing real circuits.

Answer (score 0):

Modelling using the drude model of conductivity

$$m \frac{dv}{dt} = q E - \frac{m}{T}v$$

Here this is just newtons second law with a constant electric field, as present in dc circuits, and a resistive term proportional to the velocity. T is the relaxation time and m is the mass on the electron.

$$m \frac{dv}{dt} + \frac{m}{T}v = q E $$

It can be shown that the particular solution to this differential equation is:

$$v_{p} = \frac{qT}{m}E$$

The Homogenous equation:

$$m \frac{dv}{dt} + \frac{m}{T}v = 0 $$

Can be shown to have a general solution:

$$v_{h} = -\frac{t}{T}Ae^{-\frac{t}{T}}$$

And hence the most general solution to our differential equation is therefore $v_{p} + v_{g}$

$$v = \frac{qT}{m}E  -\frac{t}{T}Ae^{-\frac{t}{T}}$$

In the limit as t tends to infinity we arrive at the following time independant steady state solution:

$$v = \frac{qT}{m}E$$

$$J = \rho v = qn v = \frac{nq^2T }{m}E$$

$$J = \sigma E$$

Where $$\sigma = \frac{nq^2T }{m}$$

These are the conclusion if you are to follow the drude model. This is also not taking into account components that do various things, wire bends.

Comment: Why does it not work at the wire bends and how do you analyze the situation there?

Comment: It's to do with the fact that when analysing the velocity in the differential equation we model it as a single electron. When we input it into the current density we assume a velocity field with  this nature in all space. This constant velocity field in all of space is one that inherently models the electrons travelling in a straight line. In this model it is therefore not accurate to extend this to when the electron collides with an somewhat unknown (to the model) force of the wire. Transients moving in a circle could be different depending on how the electrons reflect off the wire

Answer (score 0):

In a justly famous publication, Brayton & Moser:[A THEORY OF NONLINEAR NETWORKS](https://www.ams.org/journals/qam/1964-22-01/S0033-569X-1964-0169746-7/) prove that
a general non-linear RLC circuit can be transformed in a system of ordinary differential equations of the form:
$$\begin{align}
L_{\rho}\frac{di_{\rho}}{dt} &= \frac{dP}{di_{\rho}}, \quad \rho =1,2....,r\\
C_{\sigma}\frac{dv_{\sigma}}{dt} &= -\frac{dP}{di_{\rho}}, \quad \sigma=r+1,r+2....,r+s
\end{align}$$
where the $i_{\rho}$ represent the currents in the inductors and $v_{\sigma}$, the voltages across the capacitors. The function $P(i, v)$ describes the physical properties of the *resistive* part of the circuit. Based on the function $P(i,v)$ that depends *only* on the resistive part of the circuit they go on to show that:

> Especially in case a circuit contains negative resistors is it of interest to find criteria which guarantee that the solutions approach the equilibria as time increases and therefore do not oscillate. We saw that this is generally the case for RC-circuits and similarly for RL-circuits. On the other hand, RLC-circuits certainly will admit oscillations in general even in the linear case. But one would expect a nonoscillatory behavior of circuits in which the inductance—or a quantity of the dimension $\frac{L}{R^2C}$—is sufficiently small. Such criteria for nonoscillation will be derived in section 8. The main idea is to associate with the differential equation another metric which is positive and so find a function $P^*$ which decreases along the solutions.